# Как вставить комментарии трансляции YouTube на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, youtube

Хочу вывести на странице сайта трансляцию с YouTube, но прямая трансляция выводится без комментариев, только окно видео. Как вывести комментарии прямой трансляции? 
P.S Сайт на Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите идентификатор прямой трансляции. Его можно найти в URL на странице просмотра. Например, в ссылке youtube.com/watch?v=12345 идентификатор – 12345.

Если вы создали трансляцию в разделе "Начать эфир", чтобы получить ссылку, просто нажмите правой кнопкой мыши в окне проигрывателя и выберите Копировать URL видео.
Возьмите URL домена, в котором расположен сторонний сайт. Например, в адресе www.example.com/youtube_chat URL домена – www.example.com.

Составьте URL для встраивания по такому шаблону: https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=12345&embed_domain=www.example.com.

Это и есть ссылка для окна iframe. Примечание. Значение embed_domain должно соответствовать URL страницы, на которую вы хотите встроить чат. Если они будут различаться, модуль с комментариями не загрузится.